# SwiftUI.Font How to apply UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier

Tags: swiftui, uifont, uifontdescriptor

A `UIFont` can easily be setup via the font descriptor, e.g.

```
let settings: [UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey: Int] = [            
   .featureIdentifier: kStylisticAlternativesType,
   .typeIdentifier: 2]

let descriptor = someBaseFont.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([.featureSettings: [settings]])
let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: size)
```

(How) is it possible to achieve the same in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 4):

No direct way for now, but here is a solution:

```
// .. your above code
let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: size)
let myFont = Font(newFont as CTFont)                       // << here !!
```

Comment: Mh not what I was hoping for but it does work. Thank you

Comment: @benrudhart Usual Apple